# Loopback: return error from beforeValidation hook

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, jugglingdb

I need to make custom validation of instance before saving it to MySQL DB.
So I perform (async) check inside `beforeValidate` model hook.

```
MyModel.beforeValidate = function(next){
  // async check that finally calls next() or next(new Error('fail'))
}
```

But when check fails and I pass Error obj to `next` function, the execution continues anyway. 
Is there any way to stop execution and response to client with error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in the framework, see https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/614

I am working on a new hook implementation that will not have issues like the one you have experienced, see [loopback-datasource-juggler#367](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/issues/367) and the pull request [loopback-datasource-juggler#403](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/pull/403)

Comment: Thanks for your work! Attaching link to the more complete description https://gist.github.com/bajtos/b8157112452eeaf984c9#file-new-hooks-docs-md